# Can I delete rank_math_old_schema_data from my database options?

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, phpmyadmin

In the process of optimizing page loading speed for WordPress, I've noticed that the "rank_math_old_schema_data" takes up a significant amount of storage space. To further improve the website's loading speed and database performance, I want to delete "rank_math_old_schema_data" to help speed up the site. However, I'm not sure if it's safe to delete "rank_math_old_schema_data" and whether it will cause any issues on the website. I would appreciate your guidance on this. Thank you.

Can I delete rank_math_old_schema_data from my database options?